# Set Value before save

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I was wondering if there is any way to set a value to an entity onsave?

Because I'm working on a multi tenant web application and I would like to set the the current tenant ID (through simple DI service).

I tried using `HasDefaultValue()` in Fluent API, however this will try to convert to a SQL function. So this doesn't work for me.

```
builder.Entity<Order>( )
    .HasQueryFilter(p => p.TenantId == _tenantProvider.GetTenantId())
    .Property(p => p.TenantId)
    .HasDefaultValue(_tenantProvider.GetTenantId());
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set it in the constructor of Order? This is a bit confusing as it's trivial to solve.

Comment: @Will I agree with the fact that it's very trivial, and setting through constructor is also the current approach. I was just curious if there is any easier more abstracted way of doing this

Comment: You want to set it for just added entities or also for modified?

Comment: @IvanStoev assume added entities will be enough, I don't think this value will changes unless it happens explicitly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could override the [DbContext.SaveChanges()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-2.1) method and iterate the ChangeTracker entries:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries()) // Iterate all made changes
    {
        if (entityEntry.Entity is Order order)
        {
            if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added) // If you want to update TenantId when Order is added
            {
                order.TenantId = _tenantProvider.GetTenantId();
            }
            else if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified) // If you want to update TenantId when Order is modified
            {
                order.TenantId = _tenantProvider.GetTenantId();
            }
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Of course, this needs the tenant provider to be injected into your context.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I ended up creating a simple interface with TenantId and adding in to all the entities that I needed.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in `efcore`?

Answer (score 6):

EF Core [value generation on add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties) with custom [ValueGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.valuegeneration.valuegenerator)

> Generates values for properties when an entity is added to a context.

could be utilized to assign `TenantId` to the new entities. Inside the `Next` method you could obtain the `TenantId` from the context (or some service).

Taking your sample, the value generator could be a nested class inside your `DbContext` like this:

```
class TenantIdValueGenerator : ValueGenerator<int>
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;
    public override int Next(EntityEntry entry) => GetTenantId(entry.Context);
    int GetTenantId(DbContext context) => ((YourDbContext)context)._tenantProvider.GetTenantId();
}
```

The all you need is to assign the generator to `TenantId` property using some of the [HasValueGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder.hasvaluegenerator?view=efcore-2.1) fluent API.

The only problem is that by design the value generators are called only if the property does not have explicitly set value (for `int` property - if the value is `0`).

So the better approach it to abstract (and fully control) the `TenantId` property by removing it from entity models and replacing it with [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties).

Hence my suggestion is, remove the `TenantId` from entity classes and call the following method inside your `OnModelCreating` for each entity that needs `TenantId` column:

```
void ConfigureTenant<TEntity>(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) where TEntity : class
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>(builder =>
    {
        builder.Property<int>("TenantId")
            .HasValueGenerator<TenantIdValueGenerator>();

        builder.HasQueryFilter(e => EF.Property<int>(e, "TenantId") == _tenantProvider.GetTenantId());
    });
}
```

Comment: question, how do you make Update() and UpdateRange() work with this when TenantId is part of primary key? Since TenantId cannot be set it defaults to 0, when Update() is called, the entity is marked as added since one of the key in the composite key has a default value.

Comment: @herme0 This is for `Added` items only. Normally such field is not updated and is not part of the PK. Handling updateable property which is part of the PK is not a trivial task because the combination of  `HasValueGenerator` + `.ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` is not supported for such properties, and also `ChangeTracker` events happen after the entity is being tracked, hence the key properties cannot be changed at that time. Same for `Remove[Range]`. Simply currently there is no extension point where you can do such thing generically. The key properties should really be provided in advance.

Comment: This is an absolute beauty. Clean. Separation of concerns. Hiding the field that has no actual domain value and removing the risk of "forgetting to set it". Have my upvote!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using EF Core 5+, then you have the option of using the [`SavingChanges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/events#events-raised-by-ef-core) event. This will allow you to set your custom logic for both `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` without having to override both methods.

Example:

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> dbContextOptions, ITenantProvider tenantProvider) : base(dbContextOptions)
{
    SavingChanges += (sender, args) =>
    {
        foreach (var orderEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries<Order>())
        {
            if (orderEntity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                orderEntity.Entity.TenantId = tenantProvider.GetTenantId();
            }
        }
    };
}
```