# ef core - update composite primary key

Tags: entity-framework-core, multi-tenant

I have several tables with composite key { Id + OrgId }. Id is provided by the user of the application, OrgId is handled by the system. I would like to set OrgId for all instances of these tables, without having to go to each repo then set OrgId manually before attaching.

How can I do this?

In the case where OrgId is not part of the primary key, I overrid SaveChanges() to update all tracked entities having OrgId before calling the base implementation. This approach does not work when OrgId is part of the primary key because we cannot update primary key of an entity once it is tracked.

Comment: Few questions. (1) Where are you getting the desired OrgId from? (2) You need to set it for added entities only, correct? (3) What's the EF Core version?

Comment: Anyway, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954659/set-value-before-save/52956755#52956755 for reliable way of assigning TenantId taken from `DbContext` instance to added entities.

Comment: Very interesting approach; I was able to get around the issue but I might switch to this for future enhancement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So inside the `SaveChanges()` override I set `entry.Entity.OrgId`, `entry.OriginalValues["OrgId"]`, and `entry.CurrentValues["OrgId"]` with the same value. I no longer get the exception. Also, at this stage I made sure to mark OrgId as `.ValueGeneratedNever()`.

Although, I would recommend taking a look at @IvanStoev's solution.